# "Эффективный" метод определения соприкосновения

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, математика, оптимизация

Допустим есть игрок и поле, соприкосновение игрока определяется самым обычным способом: проверяется соприкосновение с каждым элементом в сцене, но если элементов слишком много то этот метод будет неэффективен. Есть аналогичные методы для этого?

Comment: Проверяется столкновение только игрока с объектами, или между объектами тоже? Можно разбить поле на квадраты и проверять столкновение только с объектами в квадрате, где находится игрок.

Comment: как правильно заметил @insolor, поле можно разбить на "локации" и производить сравнения только внутри той локации, где находится игрок.

Comment: Или сделать некий радиус у игрока и проверять соприкосновение с элементами в этом радиусе.

Comment: @Duoxx, этот вариант неэффективный: нужно будет сначала для всех объектов проверить, что они попадают в этот радиус, а потом еще проверить на столкновение с игроком. Это дважды проверка коллизии по сути. При разбивке карты на квадраты предметы привязываются к определенному квадрату, каждый раз перепроверять нахождение в квадрате не нужно, только при перемещении предмета нужно будет проверить, не ушел ли он в другой квадрат.

Comment: тут изобретают квадродерево или kd-дерево =)

Comment: А такое понятие как триггер уже не актуален? Они обычно уже реализованы. Или вы ручками сами хотите что то написать? И да...если сами хотите написать, то скажите что можно использовать для определения (например у вас есть координаты или что то ещё) или напишите на чем будите реализовать.

Comment: Ну банальный метод оптимизации, можно откидывать все объекты, которые не пересекаются прямоугольниками их координат. То есть, любая сложная фигура, допустим круг, вписана в квадрат, который представляет максимальные и минимальные координаты объекта. Достаточно хранить эти самые координаты в объекте и тогда можно не проверять для сложных объектов все изгибы, а только проверить те, чьи  координаты пересекаются. Для сложных объектов может упростить задачу минимум на порядок